# Yii2 - prevent access to specific files like controller

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii2, yii-url-manager

[image]

How can i prevent access to files like model or controller using yii options
without writing a very big .htaccess

[image: my htaccess file is]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the framework files will be accessible from a http request if you [set up the server correctly](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html#configuring-web-servers).

In Yii2 the DOCUMENT ROOT points to the `~/backend/web` and `~/frontend/web` subdirs respectively, where only `index.php` and static files should be (notably the auto-generated `assets` folder).